# How to launch Docker Containers using Ansible

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, dockerfile

I am writing a playbook where I want to build and image and start some containers for that image. I was able to build an image but my containers are not getting started. 
They are being created successfully but not in running state.

Can someone help what am i missing?

```
- name: Manage Docker instances via Ansible
  hosts: shashank-VM
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Building an image from Dockerfile
      docker_image:
        build:
          path: .
          pull: yes
        name: web
        source: build

    - name: Starting Docker Containers
      docker_container:
        name: my-app-{{ item }}
        image: web:latest
        state: started
      with_sequence: count=4
```

From the below you can see the containers are created but if i do sudo docker ps I don't see anything.

```
TASK [Starting Docker Containers] ************************************************************************************************************
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.9) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
changed: [shashank-VM] => (item=1)
changed: [shashank-VM] => (item=2)
changed: [shashank-VM] => (item=3)
changed: [shashank-VM] => (item=4)
```

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
shashank@shashank-VM:~/docker_project$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
d5b586266f15        web_new             "/bin/bash"         2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                       myvm-app-4
ea45cc1fcf3c        web_new             "/bin/bash"         2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                       myvm-app-3
1e685f3d1368        web_new             "/bin/bash"         2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                       myvm-app-2
5d03750c3fd2        web_new             "/bin/bash"         2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                       myvm-app-1
shashank@shashank-VM:~/docker_project$ sudo docker run -d web_new
6e937d7a8e75c04ea9dc6769fa41b00f5bf455e6f947f002d181d105b94c7265
shashank@shashank-VM:~/docker_project$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
shashank@shashank-VM:~/docker_project$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
6e937d7a8e75        web_new             "/bin/bash"         14 seconds ago      Exited (0) 13 seconds ago                       agitated_bartik
```

Dockerfile content -

```
FROM debian:8.5
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN echo 'Default page. Nginx is in your container. ' \
>/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
EXPOSE 8085
```

Comment: Please run playbook with `-v` or `-vv` option. It will give more debug on output.

Comment: If you `docker run web:latest` outside this Ansible playbook setup, does the container work?

Comment: Does your container start normally when you run it manually? `docker run -d web:latest`? If it doesn’t, then please provide your Dockerfile here.

Comment: @vkozyrev - You are right. It is not starting. I removed the latest tried running the below command. It presented with an ID but then when i do sudo docker ps I can't see anything.
What could be the reason?
 
I have edited the question with some more details

Comment: Aren't you missing CMD / ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with Ansible.

Your Docker image is based on `debian:8.5`, which when run simply starts a shell. If the shell isn't connected to a terminal, it will exit immediately. E.g., try running:

```
docker run debian:8.5
```

If you expect your image to run a persistent service (like `nginx`), you need to arrange for `nginx` to run when you start a container from your image. You do this suing the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` directives in your Dockerfile.

For example:

```
FROM debian:8.5
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN echo 'Default page. Nginx is in your container. ' \
>/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
EXPOSE 8085
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. However i tried something else. I added this in my docker file to build a new image from ubuntu and tried installing apache2 but it is getting stuck here -

```TASK [Building an image from Dockerfile] *****************************************************************************************************```

And the apache is not getting installed.

Comment: ```FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
ADD . /var/www/html
ENTRYPOINT apachectl -D FOREGROUND
EXPOSE 8082```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't follow what you're trying to do. In your question, you're installing `nginx`, not Apache, so I wouldn't expect Apache to work. It might be better if you either update the existing question or open a new question. Please don't try to provide code samples in comments because it's not possible to format them correctly.

Comment: Hi, Sorry it's my bad. Actually I had to use the flag in my docker file to avoid the user input that's why i was facing the issue. Everything sorted now. 
I am now facing another issue for which I will post anoither question. Thanks for all the help.